# Word suggestion for removing something specific or to hide evidence

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm programing an interface for log files which admins can "delete" the entire file, "clean" the file (remove dupes), and another function where the admin can delete specific words out of the file.

I'm trying to think of a one or two word description for the last case of removing evidence or deleting a specific word.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try [redact](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redact) or [expunge](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expunge). You can tell I'm a fan of the SCP Foundation.

Comment: I think redact fits the profile. I thought about expunge before posting this but it would have been misleading for deleting the entire file. Thanks! +rep if you post as answer

Comment: Answered questions _do_ make the entire site better. Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [redact](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redact) works best.

> **REDACT**
>
> *transitive verb*
>   1. to put in writing :  [frame](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frame)
>   2. to select or adapt (as by obscuring or removing sensitive information) for publication or release; *broadly* :  [edit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/edit)
>   3. to obscure or remove (text) from a document prior to publication or release